# TextView height as same as RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-relativelayout

I've a RelativeLayout (1) and in this Layout is a TextView and another RelativeLayout (2). The RelativeLayout (2) has a dynamic height and I want the TextView should has the same height as the RelativeLayout (2). Is this with `XML` possible?

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Some Text..."/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    ...

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried with `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First change the parent layout from `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` then set its `orientation attribute` to `vertical`

Next add `layout_weight` with the value of 1 to both children: `TextView and inner RelativeLayout`

```
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

If the above is not what you expect but a dynamic change on textview in reference to a change in height of the relative layout, I would say technically that is not possible with XML. You would have to write some codes to handle change events and update the view height when necessary.